# Django how to send array to JavaScript for dynamically display pie chart?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have an array in Django views.py and I want to send it to HTML and display a piechart, but
failed, I've tried many other methods and read many tutorials, in most of the case, they have
a field in models that store some number, and they display those number. In my case, I need to
calculate the subtotal of tasks that are in different states. I'm not sure how to output those
data to chart.js with proper labels or any other piechart if there's any recommendation?
[image: pie chart became rectangles]

views.py

```py
def visualisation(request, project_id):
    
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
   
    counts_data = Todo.objects.aggregate(
        to_do_count=Count('id', filter=Q(status='to_do')),
        in_progress_count=Count('id', filter=Q(status='in_progress')),
        done_count=Count('id', filter=Q(status='done'))
        )

    
    return render(request, 'todo_lists/progress.html', {"counts_data": counts_data})
```

html

```html
<script>
 
$(document).ready(function() {
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'doughnut',
data: {
    labels: [1,2,3],
    
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',

        data:{{counts_data}},
        
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
options: {
    responsive:false
    
}
});
});
</script>
```

[image: pie chart not show up properly]

Comment: just create an object to store the array in javascript: `var obj = {{counts_data}};`. And using that object's value create the pie chart.

Comment: @AjayLingayat Thanks for your help, I tried, but still not work, any other idea?

Comment: @NikiGrey please show the rendered data in line `data:{{counts_data}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the data in a structured manner for chart.js
Chart JS Data Structures https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html
Simply you could follow the Primitive structure as shown below or you could follow the Object structure with custom properties (need to do further data formatting and parsing).

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                // labels format ['label1', 'label2', 'label3', ]
                // you can choose to have a static labels if you are sure that 
                // there is always a specific number of labels
                labels: [{% for label in counts_data %} '{{ label }}', {% endfor %}],

                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',

                    // data format [value1, value2, value3, ]
                    data: [{% for label, value in counts_data.items() %} {{ value }}, {% endfor %}],

                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: false

            }
        });
    });
```

[image]

In your views, `Todo.objects.aggregate(...)` should return something like this (Values are provided as an example):

`{'to_do_count': 3, 'in_progress_count': 6, 'done_count': 1}`

```py
    counts_data = Todo.objects.aggregate(
        to_do_count=Count('id', filter=Q(status='to_do')),
        in_progress_count=Count('id', filter=Q(status='in_progress')),
        done_count=Count('id', filter=Q(status='done'))
        )
    # counts_data = {'to_do_count': 3, 'in_progress_count': 6, 'done_count': 1}
```

This dictionary is then passed to the context with the key named as `counts_data`. Using this key name loop through the dictionary to create `labels` and `data`

`labels: [{% for label in counts_data %} '{{ label }}', {% endfor %}],` rendered as `labels: [ 'to_do_count',  'in_progress_count',  'done_count', ],`

`data: [{% for label, value in counts_data.items() %} {{ value }}, {% endfor %}],` rendered as `data: [ 3,  6,  1, ],`

Comment: Hi Achuth, looks good, could u show me how to make change to views.py, please? I'm stuck in ouput the format required

Comment: I still don't know how I can ouput some thing like[value1, value2, value3], in my understanding, the counts_data=...agregate(..., ..., ...) is a list similar to value list (value1, value2, value3), but then when I return it need to be a dict, so I turn it context = {"counts_data", counts_data}, which is similar to {counts_data1: (value1, value2, value3), counts_data2:(value1, value, value3),...}, so I'm not sure how I can output data like [value1, value2,value3]

Comment: I tried to put them into one queryset, but a queryset can only get or filter one status, I have 3 status, so I'm confused, it would be great if u could explain a little bit? Cheers

Comment: in your views, when you call the aggregate() you would get value in `counts_data` which would be in format of a dictionary as `{'to_do_count': 1, 'in_progress_count': 1, 'done_count': 1}` (please don't mind the values). This is assigned to the context with key as `counts_data` which is then used in html to access the dictionary. With looping you are actually accessing the keys and values in the dictionary to create the data in the format as specified. Hope this helps. (to make sure, you can inspect the code using browser dev tools and see how it is rendered)

Comment: about having 3 status in a queryset: please check the last example in this section from the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset  You can see that a dictionary is returned. So, in the code provided you should get a return value something like `{'to_do_count': 1, 'in_progress_count': 1, 'done_count': 1}` and not like `{counts_data1: (value1, value2, value3), counts_data2:(value1, value, value3),...}`

Comment: So context = {"counts_data": counts_data} should  returns {'to_do_count': 1, 'in_progress_count': 1, 'done_count': 1}, got it, thank you for your detailed explanation, Achuth

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 
$(document).ready(function() {
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'doughnut',
data: {
    labels: [1,2,3],
    
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',

        data:counts_data,

        success: function (data){
        $('#todocount').html(counts_data.to_do_count);
        $('#progress_count').html(counts_data.in_progress_count);

        $('#progress_done').html(counts_data.done_count);

    }
        
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
options: {
    responsive:false
    
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for your help, I tried your method, but not working, do you have any other idea?